# XFORMS: Multiple xforms-submit-done events being fired

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms

I have a situation where the response from a web service (authentication) is being examined before performing another xforms:send.  The problem I have is that the xforms-submit-done is being hit for both the form submission and the authentication.

The code is given below:

```
 <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="Authenticate-submission" context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">
    <xf:action if="contains(//AuthenticateReturn,'true')"> 
         <!-- If correctly Authenticated, then continue with the form submission -->
         <xf:send submission="SubmitForm-submission"/>
         <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="SubmitForm-submission" />
         <!-- Response actions -->
         <xf:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="SubmitForm-submission" context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">
             <!-- This section is entered twice, once for the Authenticate-submission andonce for the SubmitForm-submission -->
             <xf:message level="modal">Submission complete</xf:message>    
         </xf:action>
    </xf:action>
 </xf:action>
```

How can I amend my code to ensure that the message is ONLY displayed after a sucessful submission to the SubmitForm-submission, and not to the Authenticate-submission?

TIA
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, by changing ev.observer to ev.target in the xforms-submit-done handler.